# jmf file play error

Tags: java, swing, jmf

I have taken the code from the url  and tried to play a file of mpg format as shown below:

Code URL: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2912

File URL: http://www.fileformat.info/format/mpeg/sample/index.htm

I am getting an error as follows:

```
  Unable to handle format: MPEG, 320x200, FrameRate=23.9, Length=96000
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@75982fc1
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@75982fc1
```

As iam new to jmf, kindly help me in this issue.

Comment: Will the standard JMF player play that video?  If not, it means that the codec (a separate thing to the file type of MPG) is not supported by JMF.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I have no idea about that. Please tell me how to check this.

Comment: *"I have no idea about that."*  I don't intend to write a tutorial.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson sorry if i had asked a dumb question. An address or a source of jmf tutorial will mean much to me....

Comment: I did not mean I had the link to a JMF tutorial.  What I meant was, what do you not understand, specifically?  (And I do mean what do you not understand, after doing some research on the term 'codec'?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used that code before and that sample can play only some kind of videos with high resolution. Try getting a 720p mpg file(perhaps a tv series dvd rip) and playing it.